# How to force applications to not start maximised in Awesome WM?

Tags: firefox, awesome, window-management, lua

How to reproduce:

1. `ssh -X user@host firefox` (or some other X application).
2. Maximise the window.
3. Close the application.
4. Open the application in Awesome WM (tried only locally, but should also work remotely).

Result: The window is still maximised.

Since I *never* use the maximise functionality in Awesome, and often use it in other window managers, I'd like to unset the maximisation whenever I open X applications in Awesome.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796675/96588):

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" },
  properties = { tag = tags[math.min(2, screen.count())][2],
                 maximized_vertical = false, maximized_horizontal = false } },
```

Firefox *does* start in tag 2, but it's still maximised. Any idea how to unset the maximisation, for Firefox specifically, but even better for all X applications?

Comment: I suspect that Firefox deliberately sidesteps WM hints. If you can't find a better way, consider a timed trigger that unmaximizes Firefox.

Comment: Firefox is not the only application to preserve its own window settings on exit (for example, the Pan newsreader does this).  It looks an awful lot like there's a race condition between Awesome setting up the window, and the application restoring its saved settings.  As such, you may be stuck doing it with a timed trigger as the previous commenter noted, or doing it by hand (the default key mapping for toggling window maximization in Awesome is MOD + `m`).

Comment: Thanks both! @ewhac, your comment could be converted to an answer. Even better if you know how to create a timed trigger in Awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted Comment from @ewhac into an answer:

Firefox is not the only application to preserve its own window settings on exit (for example, the Pan newsreader does this). It looks an awful lot like there's a race condition between Awesome setting up the window, and the application restoring its saved settings.

As such, you may be stuck doing it with a **timed trigger** as the previous commenter noted, or doing it by hand (the default key mapping for toggling window maximization in Awesome is MOD + m).

Comment: @ewhac: you can post another answer, then I will delete this one